# Set an x-axis of a histogram in matlab to get a subset of the histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a histogram I plotted in matlab and I want to work with only a section of that histogram. I have found how to change the x-axis overall, but that just plots the entire histogram over this new axis instead of just pulling the subset of the histogram. Is there any way just to work with that section of the histogram by selecting a certain x-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot exactly as much of the histogram as you want by choosing a subsection of the matrix,

```
bins = 100
xmin = 40
xmax = 60
[f,x]=hist(randn(1000000,1),bins);
bar(x(xmin:xmax),f(xmin:xmax))
```

Alternatively, you can plot over a specified range of x bin values,

```
xvalues = -1:0.1:0.9;
[f,x]=hist(randn(1000000,1),xvalues);   
bar(x,f,'b')
```

but all the values outside this range will be collected in the bins at either end if the range.